# Pandas DataFrame - 1 Column to Multiple Columns and 1 Column as Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

| ID | Name | Stages | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Interview | 02/01/2022 |
| 2 | Mario | Apply | 01/01/2022 |
| 3 | Luis | Interview | 02/01/2022 |
| 2 | Mario | Interview | 02/01/2022 |
| 2 | Mario | Offer | 03/01/2022 |
| 3 | Luis | Offer | 03/01/2022 |

and I want to make it look like this:

| ID | Name | Apply | Interview | Offer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | NaN | 02/01/2022 | NaN |
| 2 | Mario | 01/01/2022 | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |
| 3 | Luis | NaN | 02/01/2022 | 03/01/2022 |

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.pivot( index = ['index','Name'],columns = ['Stages'], values = 'Dates')
```

This shows the dates by stage, but it doesn't group by Name and I've been stuck trying other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

`reset_index` after the pivot, not before, and use `ID` not `index` as new index:

```
(df.pivot(index=['ID','Name'], columns='Stages', values='Date')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
   ID   Name       Apply   Interview       Offer
0   1   John         NaN  02/01/2022         NaN
1   2  Mario  01/01/2022  02/01/2022  03/01/2022
2   3   Luis         NaN  02/01/2022  03/01/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 'index' part of your code to get desired results

```
df = df.pivot( index = ['Name'],columns = ['Stages'], values = 'Date')
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df[['Name', 'Apply', 'Interview', 'Offer']]
```